# how to change mat-datepicker input on click button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker, mat-datepicker

I am trying to bind date property to mat-datepicker's input when im click on nextDate button.
how can I do it?
I am using `[(ngModel)]` but it not working.

my html code

```
<input   [(ngModel)]="departureDate"  [min]="minDate"
(dateInput)="onDateChange($event)" [matDatepicker]="picker"  placeholder="date"  (click)="_openCalendar(picker)" #elementToFocus>
<button (click)="nextDate()" class="date-btn" type="submit"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button>
<button class="date-btn" type="submit"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon></button>
<mat-datepicker #picker="matDatepicker" (closed)="_closeCalendar($event)"></mat-datepicker>
```

and my method in ts :

```
 nextDate(){
this.departureDate.setDate(this.departureDate.getDate() + 1) }
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you want to get selected date in departuteDate?

Comment: If you are using ngModel this.departureDate.getDate() +1 you don't need dot value

Comment: Hi maruthi.im want to add 1 day to departureDate when I'm click to nextDate() , and show new departureDate value to input